Prove that x(t)↦y(t) being Time Invariant implies dx(t)/dt↦dy(t)/dt also TI
If we have a time invariant system $ x(t) \mapsto y(t) $, can we prove that $ \dfrac{dx(t)}{dt} \mapsto \dfrac{dy(t) } {dt} $ is also a time invariant system?
I feel like it's very obvious but can't find a clear way to prove it.
Edit: This is how my book defines time invariance.

A system is time-invariant if a time-shift
of the input signal results in the same
time-shift of the output signal.

From what I understand it means that,
If $x(t)  \xrightarrow{\text{yields} } y(t),\,\,$ then system is time invariant if $x(t-t_0) \xrightarrow{\text{yields}} y(t-t_0)$ for any $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$

What property must hold for a system to be deemed time-invariant? Be sure to bear in mind that the system might not be linear when answering. Please don't answer by writing a comment in response; instead, edit your question to say something like "A system is said to be a time-invariant system if ......"  You can edit your question by clicking on the Edit link at the bottom of your question

You are right, it is very obvious if you think about it correctly. A nonlinear system is uniquely and consistently specified by listing all possible inputs together with all possible outputs. (Linearity would require a certain consistency given by the linear closure any subsets.) So if your input set is known to be time invariant, then this constraint is part of your input/output assignment. Any operation that commutes with time-shifts, like taking the time derivative, will again produce a set of input/ouputs that describes a time invariant system.

@Jazzmaniac What is an input set that is time-invariant? Could you please explain a little more?

The system is defined by a set $S = { x\mapsto y }$ of input/output pairs. It is time invariant iff $(x \mapsto y) \in S \implies (Tx \mapsto Ty) \in S$, for all possible time shift operators $T$. If we construct a new system from the given system such that $S' = { \partial_t x \mapsto \partial_t y : (x \mapsto y) \in S }$, then it follows that $S'$ is time invariant iff $S$ is time invariant, because $\partial_t$ and $T$ commute.

@DilipSarwate, sorry, forgot to highlight you.
